# Copy batch file into newly created folder of same name

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to create a batch file which will search for .docx files in my folder and then for each of them create a separate directory and then copy each .docx file inside that directory. My folder contains of hundreds of files with so long names and housekeeping is a nightmare!

I have searched around and found some code which helps me to create a new directory for each .docx file. Here is the link.. "[Win 7: CMD batch file for creating directories based on filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119194/win-7-cmd-batch-file-for-creating-directories-based-on-filenames)"

The code which ONLY creates new directory for the file

```
for %%I in (*.docx) do mkdir "%%~pnI"
```

However how do I COPY the file INTO the newly created directory with the same name?

E.g file name is 20160611150424.docx (where numbers are YYYY MM DD HH MM SS) and using the code above it creates a file called 20160611150424.

How do i use batch file to copy this file into this folder? Which is the appropriate code to be used?

Many thanks,

NewLearner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read `copy /?`: you could copy a file into newly created directory *specifying the destination as a folder* without file name and extension and `copy` command will retain them):

```
for %%I in (*.docx) do (
    mkdir "%%~pnI" 2>NUL
    copy /B "%%~fI" "%%~pnI\"
)
```

or *specify the destination with file name and extension explicitly* as follows:

```
for %%I in (*.docx) do (
    mkdir "%%~pnI" 2>NUL
    copy /B "%%~fI" "%%~pnI\%%~nxI"
)
```

Note that `2>NUL` will suppress error message `A subdirectory or file a already exists` possibly generated by `mkdir` command if this is the case.

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%%~nxI` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`2>NUL`  etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)